# include scale and coordinates in R map

Tags: r, maps, geospatial

I am drawing a map in R with the following code:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

map('worldHires',c('UK'),
    xlim=c(-10,-1),
    ylim=c(56,59.5))  
points(-5.65,56.7233,col=2,pch=18)
```

resulting in

[image]

How can I add a scale to the map as well as a box surrounding it with the latitude and longitude shown? Something similar to:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `map.scale` and `north.arrow` from `GISTools` package. But as your map is not projected, the scale will certainly be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maps` package has also a function `map.axes` and `map.scales`.

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

map('worldHires',c('UK'), xlim=c(-10,-1),
    ylim=c(56,59.5))

points(-5.65,56.7233,col=2,pch=18)
map.axes()
map.scale()
```

gives you

[image]

### Edit 1

If you look at the code of `map.axes` you see that it simply calling `axis` and `box`. One way would be to do that manually and adjust the labels.

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

m <- map('worldHires',c('UK'), xlim=c(-10,-1),
         ylim=c(56,59.5), mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4))

points(-5.65,56.7233,col=2,pch=18)

xat <- pretty(m$range[1:2])
xlab <- paste0(xat, " E")

yat <- pretty(m$range[3:4])
ylab <- paste0(yat, " N")

box()
axis(1, at=xat, labels=xlab)
axis(2, las=TRUE, at=yat, labels=ylab)
axis(3, at=xat, labels=xlab)
axis(4, las=TRUE, at=yat, labels=ylab)
map.scale(y=59)
```

This would give you the same picture with adjusted labels
[image]

### Edit 2:

Or use the `raster::degreeLabels*` function as suggested by @Pascal.

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(raster)

m <- map('worldHires',c('UK'), xlim=c(-10,-1),
         ylim=c(56,59.5), mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4))

points(-5.65,56.7233,col=2,pch=18)

xat <- pretty(m$range[1:2])
xlab <- parse(text=degreeLabelsEW(xat))

yat <- pretty(m$range[3:4])
ylab <- parse(text=degreeLabelsNS(yat))


box()
axis(1, at=xat, labels=xlab)
axis(2, las=TRUE, at=yat, labels=ylab)
axis(3, at=xat, labels=xlab)
axis(4, las=TRUE, at=yat, labels=ylab)

map.scale(y=59)
```

[image]

Comment: And how do you add x and y labels e.g. N and E?

Comment: `degreeLabelsEW` and `degreeLabelsNS` in `raster` package. Usage: `parse(text=degreeLabelsEW())` and `parse(text=degreeLabelsNS())`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on rengis answer:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(GISTools)
library(raster)

map('worldHires',c('UK'), xlim=c(-10,-1), ylim=c(56,59.5))
points(-5.65,56.7233,col=2,pch=18)
maps::map.scale(-9.5,56.2)
axis(1, at = seq(-10,-2,2), parse(text=degreeLabelsEW(seq(-10,-2,2))))
axis(2, at = seq(56,59,1), parse(text=degreeLabelsNS(seq(56,59,1))))
north.arrow(-8.5, 59, 0.1, "N")
box()
```

[image]